# Running Monero Remote node

Tags: daemon, network, nodes

Im having some difficulty getting a remote node setup, as far as i understand all you need is a fully synced node. and then you add some start up flags to get the remote node running currently im trying with the below startup flags

```
--rpc-bind-ip YOUR.EXTERNAL_IP.GOES.HERE --rpc-bind-port 18089 --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind
```

i've tried using both my external IP address as provided by my ISP and my internal network IP address as assigned by my router but neither are working

Whenever i try to start the Daemon with those flags i get the error 
couldn't connect to daemon 127.0.0.1 : 18081

I've tried this on 2 computers so far and cant work this out, if i can get this working ill be writing a user guide that i can slap up on getmonero.com

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems you aren't running a full node, you are trying to open monero wallet rpc. There are a lot of differences between monero wallet rpc and monero daemon.

Answer (score 1):

You use port 18089 in config, but try connect to port 18081.
Also you need set your extetnal ip and config your routers and firewalls to redirect port 18089 to you daemon host.

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence.  I imagine you are implying that something should change (because using and connecting should be to the same port), but I don't know what should change.  Is the 18081 in the table of which ports should be open at https://github.com/coincashew/coincashew/blob/master/coins/overview-xmr/guide-or-how-to-run-a-full-node.md a typo?  I have no port forwarding rules for 18089 in my router.  Do I need one?